# Pushing a UIViewController doesn't work with connections

Tags: iphone

Alright, in my rootViewController, I am able to push another viewController that I defined myself onto the screen. However, when I make any connections between that viewController and its own .h file, the program just hangs and crashes, giving me this error:

2010-06-04 15:36:13.944 pooldocfinal[11971:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label1.'

That happens when i don't connect anything besides that one UILabel. Here is the code I use to declare/push the view (named balanceViewController):

```
    - (IBAction) pushedBalanceButton
{
    balanceViewController *controller = [[balanceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"balanceViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

And here is the .h file of the view that I am pushing, it has only one thing in it:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface balanceViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

}
@end
```

And like I said, everything works unless I actually make a connection in Interface Builder between anything in balanceViewController.xib and balanceViewController.h (in this case, it is the one UILabel object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you have an IBOutlet, you need to define getters/setters.  That's what Key Value coding compliant means.  You can do this via @property statements and @synthesize statements, or manually if you so choose.

```
@interface balanceViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

@end
```

Then add

```
@synthesize label1;
```

to your implementation

EDIT - PS, don't forget to [label1 release] in your dealloc method

Answer (score 1):

You should alloc a balanceViewController, not a UIViewController.

Comment: Good point, and I fixed that, but it still freezes just the same. what else could it be?